# How do I add two expressions in derived column in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I am trying to remove the spacing and get rid of all the text after the dash.
However, I don't know how to add to expressions in SSIS

The Column Data looks like this

```
CS 1301 / 000
```

I want it to look like this

```
CS1301
```

Here is the expressions

```
REPLACE(Course," ","")      SUBSTRING(Course,1,FINDSTRING(Course,"/",1) - 1)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to accomplish the task in one statement, however, I used two derived column and this worked .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column name is `Course`, try `SUBSTRING(Course,0,2)+SUBSTRING(Course, 3,4)` You can choose to either replace the column or add it as a new column in Derived Column section of the Derived Column Transformation Editor

Answer (score 0):

did you want to nest the results of one statement in the other, like:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Course,1,FINDSTRING(Course,"/",1) - 1)," ","")
```